# macOS High Sierra: Where is the Secure Empty Trash option?

Tags: macbook-pro, high-sierra

There used to be an option to delete files securely in older versions of Mac OS X. However, I am unable to find the same in macOS High Sierra 10.13.5.

Is the option removed? If yes, what's the probable reason? As I understand, the command was useful to ensure that data could no longer be recovered from the hard drive.

I am using a Late 2013 15" retina MacBook Pro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This feature was removed in macOS 10.11 El Capitan. Per the Apple support document [About the security content of OS X El Capitan v10.11](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT205267), it was removed for security reasons.

> **Finder**
>   Available for: Mac OS X v10.6.8 and later
>
> Impact: The "Secure Empty Trash" feature may not securely delete files placed in the Trash
>
> Description: An issue existed in guaranteeing secure deletion of Trash files on some systems, such as those with flash storage. This issue was addressed by removing the "Secure Empty Trash" option.
>
> CVE-ID
>   CVE-2015-5901 : Apple

The CVE gives a small paragraph on this issue. From [NVD - CVE-2015-5901](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2015-5901):

> The Secure Empty Trash feature in Finder in Apple OS X before 10.11 improperly deletes Trash files, which might allow local users to obtain sensitive information by reading storage media, as demonstrated by reading a flash drive.

Comment: Perfect! Exactly the answer I was looking for. +1.

Comment: Wow Apple. "It's broken, so lets throw it away". I think if they took 5min to fix it they could especially since its a great feature.

Comment: @JBis In reality it is very hard to implement this feature on modern hardware - it is definitely not a "5 minute fix". On an SSD drive you're generally lucky to have a SECURE ERASE command that will safely delete everything on the drive. That's if you're lucky. You won't find a command to delete a byte range nor a single block. Implementing secure erase on top of this without sacrificing major performance or having specialized secondary storage is very, very hard.

Comment: @jksoegaard Just write over the blocks a couple times.

Comment: @jksoegaard Same in the following except with those specific blocks→ https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/327247/263848

Comment: @JBis You need to read up on SSDs. Writing over the block a couple of times will definitely not work on any modern SSD (i.e. anything sold to consumers within the last 10 years or so).

Comment: @jksoegaard https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/12503/can-wiped-ssd-data-be-recovered Fair enough.

Answer (score 2):

If you are concerned about data 'falling into the wrong hands' or just giving/selling your MBP to somebody else, the best practice is to boot into [Recovery](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314), use DiskUtility from the Utilities menu to erase the disk with elevated security overwrite passes, then reinstall macOS.

Below is a screen cap of the Security Options available in DiskUtility.

Note: the Most Secure option can take many, many hours to complete, depending on the size and rotational speed of the disk being erased.

SSD drive erasure note from [Apple](https://support.apple.com/kb/ph22241?locale=en_US):

> With a solid-state drive (SSD), secure erase options are not available in Disk Utility. For more security, consider turning on FileVault encryption when you start using your SSD drive.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems your only options are at the command line. I know of these two:

1. Install `srm` via [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/)
2. `rm -P`  see `man rm` for details

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, question concerns with confirmation of removal and the reason for the same.

Comment: No problem. I thought it did answer the "is it removed" question via "only options are command line". And as for reasons, :)  who knows, really? But I'm happy you got what you were looking for.

Comment: The reason files on SSD drives can’t be securely erased is because their controllers implement wear leveling so that writing a block to an SSD does not overwrite the old block, instead the data is written elsewhere and a pointer is set to the new data. https://askubuntu.com/questions/794612/how-to-securely-wipe-files-from-ssd-drive

Comment: The `rm(1)` man page says: "**-P** This flag has no effect.  It is kept only for backwards compatibility with 4.4BSD-Lite2."

Comment: @200_success: But that's NOT what it said in. the `January 28, 1999` version of the man page which I had on my macOS Mojave version which was current when the question was answered.